# Eclipse not displaying TextView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview

Okay, so the thing is that I'm trying to display text but it won't let me. the code is :

```
<TextView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="normal" />
```

What have I done wrong? (the text won't appear on screen)

Comment: which background you have on screen black or white?

Comment: Try to use FF000000 for text color-  if you don't specify alpha it will use 00, which is fully transparent.

Comment: Gave id to the textview, changed the text color to FF000000. I'm having the white screen.
(Code after changing) ---still not showing the text--- :

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FF000000"
  
        android:textStyle="normal" />

Comment: <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android :background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

Comment: what value your `app_name` contains in strings.xml

Answer (score 1):

1. At your string resources `app_name` might be empty or null.
2. There is another view that prevents your `TextView` to be displayed at your screen, take a look at your layout file.
3. The value for `TextView` modified to a null/empty value in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Flights"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct as it is working for me. The probable mistake you have done is that your String resource variable "app_name" is empty or you can provide the full xml code for us to have a better look at this problem.

Comment: Naddy, ok i will remove my comment